# Migrating JSF 2.2.6 to 2.2.8 cause java.lang.IllegalStateException com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased

Tags: jsf-2.2

I want to migrate my application to jsf 2.2.8 to use this [bug fix][1]

But when i try to move on with 2.2.7 or 2.2.8 , i get on the first page of my application.

The application running on Tomcat 7.042 is using Richfaces 4.3.5 & Spring 3 by the way.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>     com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:705)
>     com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.getAttributes(FacesContextImpl.java:237)
>     org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.setInstance(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:55)
>     org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContext.release(ExtendedPartialViewContext.java:64)
>     org.richfaces.context.ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.release(ExtendedPartialViewContextImpl.java:424)
>     com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.release(FacesContextImpl.java:591)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:665)
>     com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

Comment: HiI have the same issue, have you fixed it ?

Comment: This already answered in a different thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37711812/3933950